# Error: I do not know the key \tikz\general shadow

Tags: tikz-pgf

It compiles but I see an error:

```
I do not know the key \tikz\general shadow
```

This is the code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
 
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.3]
\tikzset{
    cli/.style={circle,ball color=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5pt],draw, general shadow={fill=gray!60,shadow xshift=1pt,shadow yshift=-1pt}},
    c1/.style={very thick,black},
    c2/.style={very thick,red!65!black},
    c3/.style={very thick,green!70!black}}
\node[cli] (w0) at (-2,0) {}; 
\node[cli] (w1) at (-2,-4) {};
\node[cli] (w2) at (2,-4) {};
\node[cli] (w3) at (2,0) {};
\draw[c1] (w0) -- (w1);
\draw[c1] (w0) -- (w3);
\draw[c2] (w1) to  node [black,below] {$aaa$} (w2);
\draw[c1] (w2) -- (w3);
\draw[c2] (w2) -- (w0); 
\draw[c2] (w1) -- (w3); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you compiling this on Overleaf by any chance? It failed on my local TeX Live, presumably Overleaf pushed through the error and output still

Comment: Yes, James, on Overleaf.

Comment: Did my answer fix your issue? If it did, please consider accepting it or waiting for another answer, no rush but helps keep the site clean and stops the community bot bumping it every so often

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the `shadows` TikZ library (`\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,shadows}`):

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,shadows}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
 
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.3]
\tikzset{
    cli/.style={circle,ball color=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5pt],draw, general shadow={fill=gray!60,shadow xshift=1pt,shadow yshift=-1pt}},
    c1/.style={very thick,black},
    c2/.style={very thick,red!65!black},
    c3/.style={very thick,green!70!black}}
\node[cli] (w0) at (-2,0) {}; 
\node[cli] (w1) at (-2,-4) {};
\node[cli] (w2) at (2,-4) {};
\node[cli] (w3) at (2,0) {};
\draw[c1] (w0) -- (w1);
\draw[c1] (w0) -- (w3);
\draw[c2] (w1) to  node [black,below] {$aaa$} (w2);
\draw[c1] (w2) -- (w3);
\draw[c2] (w2) -- (w0); 
\draw[c2] (w1) -- (w3); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```